# Identify memory leaks in VB.NET Windows application using SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the best way to identify memory leaks for a VB.NET 3.5 Windows application?

Comment: A few questions: Why do you think you have memory leaks? Do you use COM objects? Which version of VS do you use?

Comment: VS 2008, the reason why i am asking is because on of the forms in my application tend to get really slow as more and more people try to access it

Comment: Presumably the people aren't all sitting at one computer. If it's a Winforms app, the "more and more people" are each using their own memory on their own machines. You have either a memory leak or a scalability problem on your server. How are you getting data to your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaking window handles is a common mishap in a Winforms app.  Induced by calling Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove() without calling Dispose() on the removed control(s).  You can troubleshoot that with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick USER objects, GDI objects and Handles.  Observe the values of these columns while your app runs.  If you see USER objects climb steadily then you are not calling Dispose() on a control when you should.  Climbing GDI objects tend to be bitmaps that you don't dispose.

If that doesn't pan out then a memory profiler is your next resource.  Spend money on a decent one.